# Event setting with delegate

Tags: c#, events

Hello i create a class which contains the event and the variables :

```
namespace FS
{
      public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public readonly string SomeVarible;
    
            public SomeEventArgs (string someVarible)
            {
                SomeVarible= someVarible;
            }
        }
    }
```

and i want to use this in another class :

```
namespace FS
{
delegate void Example(object sender, SomeEventArgs e);
    public class OtherClass
    {

        public event Example example;
}
```

and i get this error :

> Error CS7025  Inconsistent accessibility: event type 'Example' is less
> accessible than event 'OtherClass.example'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified access modifier of your `delegate void Example(object sender, SomeEventArgs e);` default one is `internal`, but event in class `OtherClass` is `public`.

It's illogical to expose something to other libraries with `public` modifier, while the underlying type is only accessible inside your library, because it is `internal`.

Easiest solution is making your delegate `public`, or your event `public internal`, depends how you want to use it.

You can find more about [access modifiers here in documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)